# How do I dired delete in helm?

Tags: helm, dired

I just installed Helm and it looks really cool.  However, I don't understand how to use `dired` anymore.

I'd usually `C-x d` to see my directory, then I could do operations like add or delete files.  Now I get a helm dired buffer, which is super fast, but when I scroll to the file I'm looking for and type 'd', it's just doing auto-complete, not in a mode where I can do file operations.

What should I do instead?

My init.el has the minimal, vanilla helm additions:

```
(require 'helm-config)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") #'helm-M-x)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r b") #'helm-filtered-bookmarks)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") #'helm-find-files)
(helm-mode 1)
```

Comment: You have not entered dired, you're still inside the completing interface, you need to pick a file/directory to enter dired. When `helm-mode` is enabled, the default Emacs completing interface is replaced by helm's, hit RET to choose one file/dir.

Comment: But when I pick a folder, it just keeps going deeper and deeper into sub directories, not giving me a dired buffer.

Comment: It doesn't, I mean RET, though you can goto subdir using `C-j`.

Comment: That's not what RET does in my case, honest.  It just takes me to the sub-folder.  The only commands I have for helm were the above, so should be vanilla.

Comment: I don't think that's expected. C-x d RET, and you're in dired, with or without helm-mode.